# Visual Delay when Hiding and Showing Images successively at a fast speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have about 50 Images that should be shown one after another inside a `div`.

The delay between showing one image then another is about 750 milliseconds and decreasing with each image.

I made sure that all images are loaded before this animation kicks in, by using:

```
(window).load(function() { });
```

The animaton is done using `setTimeout`

```
var index = 1;
function newImage(index) {
var interval = setTimeout( function(){
        $("#image-container .image").css("display","none");
        $("#image-container .image:nth-child("+index+")").css("display","block");
        clearTimeout(interval);
        index = index + 1;
        newImage(index);

    },delay[index-1]);
}
```

Where `delay` is an array of delays, something like `[750,750,650,...]`.

The animation works fine, but there's a visual delay as fast as a blink of an eye, where no image is shown and only the background is visible, how can I avoid it?

Comment: have you tried use `visibility` css property instead of `display`?

Comment: @VladNikitin IT WORKED! HAHA, put it as answer! a Lesson to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `visibility` css  property instead of `display`